# Why jquery autocomplete not working with phone masking jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

Here are my library file for autocomplete:

```
<link href="css/JqueryAutoComplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Quote.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here are my library files for phone masking

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there any conflict between these files.?

Comment: is your common.js and Quote.js depends on jquery.min.js?

Comment: No these are not dependent on jquery.@Bhushan Kawadkar

Comment: are you getting any error on console? .. can you share JSFiddle for this?

Comment: I am not getting any error just at a time both the jquery functions are not working.@Bhushan Kawadkar